# Por que o contexto mudou?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo meus estudos de Javascript, e estou fazendo alguma bem simples para consumir uma API, porém recebi um erro. Antes de comentá-lo, vou mostrar meu código:

View.js

```
var model = new Model();
var response = null;
model.setUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
model.openXhr("GET");
```

Model.js

```
var Model = function() {
    var _url = null;
    var _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var _message = {};
    var _response = null;

    this.setUrl = function (url) {
        _url = url;
    }

    this.getUrl = function (url) {
        return _url;
    }

    this.openXhr = function(method) {
        _xhr.open(method, this.getUrl());
        _xhr.onload = this.onLoadXhr;
        _xhr.send();
    }

    this.onLoadXhr = function() {
        if (_xhr.status === 200)
            _message.status = "success";
        else
            _message.status = "failed";

        var response = this.parseResponse(_xhr.responseText); // this.parseResponse is not a function

        this.setResponse(response);
    }

    this.parseResponse = function(response) {
        return JSON.parse(response);
    }

    this.setResponse = function(response) {
        _response = response;
    }

    this.getResponse = function() {
        return _response;
    }


}
```

## O problema

```
var response = this.parseResponse(_xhr.responseText); // this.parseResponse is not a function
```

Vejam que chega nessa parte ele dá esse erro ao chamar a função. Printando o `this` verifiquei que ele não é do contexto da função, e sim do `_xhr`. Por quê ? Em outra parte do código eu faço uma operação parecida e não acontece isso `_xhr.onload = this.onLoadXhr;`. Aqui eu referenciei a `onLOadXhr` dentro da `openXhr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que o `_xhr.onload` vai ser corrido pela a instância do Ajax e quando fazes `_xhr.onload = this.onLoadXhr;` passas uma função, sem contexto associado, por isso vai ser-lhe dado o `this` do objeto que chamar.

Usa assim: `_xhr.onload = this.onLoadXhr.bind(this);`, dessa maneira passas o teu método, já forçando o contexto.

Um exemplo para clarificar:

```js
function Obj(fn) {
    this.teste = fn;
}

function foo(quem) {
    console.log(quem, this === window);
}

new Obj(foo).teste('dentro do obj');
foo('fora do objeto');
```

Comment: Então sempre que passar uma função como referência ela não virá com contexto associado ?

Comment: @AllanRamos depende, nesse caso a função é chamada como método de `XMLHttpRequest` e daí o contexto mudar.

Comment: Por estar associada ao objeto XHR. Se eu não tivesse esse objeto, como ficaria ?

Comment: @AllanRamos juntei um exemplo à resposta

Answer (score 1):

O normal em situações como essa é declarar uma variável para armazenar uma referência para o próprio objeto. Por exemplo:

```
var Model = function() {
    var $this = this;

    // ...

    this.onLoadXhr = function() {
        if (_xhr.status === 200)
            _message.status = "success";
        else
            _message.status = "failed";

        var response = $this.parseResponse(_xhr.responseText);

        $this.setResponse(response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

O problema com o `this` é que ele muda de acordo com o contexto. No caso, dentro de uma função, o `this` já não faz mais referência ao objeto, e sim ao contexto da função.

Answer (score 0):

Agora eu entendi, e vou explicar o ocorrido com um novo caso.

```
var Model = function() {
    this.teste = 1;

    this.firstFunction = function (url) {
        this.secondFunction();
        this.thirdFunction();
    }

    this.secondFunction = function (url) {
        console.log("second " + this.teste);
    }

    this.thirdFunction = function (url) {
        console.log("third " + this.teste);
        var a = this.fourthFunction;
        a();
    }

    this.fourthFunction = function (url) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log("fourth " + this.teste); //undefined
    }

}

var model = new Model();
model.firstFunction();
```

O `fourthFunction` perdeu o contexto ao ser passado como referência, assumindo o contexto do objeto global.

Por via de regra, sempre quando você regista uma `function` para ser executada depois, seja por causa de um CB, ou Event ou até mesmo para renomear uma function vais ter que bindar ele para o escopo original, por que se não ela vai assumir o escopo destino, ou seja, no seu caso a onLoadXhr (sem bind) esta assumindo o this como essa própria função e não mais o this da openXhr.